# Document text in XML

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

I understand the differences between XML and HTML, but one particular aspect is not clear to me.  XML is usually described as both a language that describes data, as well as a document markup language.  Because of the former definition, XML is often compared to other data-describing formats such as JSON.  Because of the latter definition, XML is *also* often compared to other document-markup languages, such as HTML.

I realize XML can function as both, but if XML is to serve as a document markup language, can document text appear between closing tags, in the same way it can with HTML?

Take the following HTML:

```
<div>
   Some text, and some <b>more</b> text.
</div>
```

Ignoring the initial XML Declaration, is the above also valid XML?  Note that the fragment `text.` is not enclosed in any tags: it appears between two *closing* tags.  This is, of course, necessary in a markup language like HTML, where the goal is to format text.  But most examples of XML I see use it to *describe data*, like:

```
<book>
  <title>Blah blah</title>
  <author>Blah blah</author>
</book>
```

In the above example, text never appears between closing tags.

So, is text (content) allowed to appear between closing tags in XML?

Comment: Yes. Also, the best way to understand XML is to consider it as a *metalanguage*.

Comment: Yes. In your HTML example, the text enclosed in bold tags is considered nested within the div just as the title is nested within book element of your XML example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is referred to as  ["mixed content"](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp)

You are correct in noting it as one of the requirements for a document
format as opposed to a data format. JSON is probably better as a data
format than XML, but because it does not allow mixed content, it cannot
replace XML as a document format.

Comment: I don't get it. Although XML allows mixed content, an XML-alike language could require that each text node was the sole child of an element. e.g., in XHTML-alike, that each text node was inside a `span` element. That would allow documents to be marked-up completely without the need to allow mixed content. It then follows that JSON *could* act as a document format. Not that I think it's a good idea, just that it would be possible.

Comment: @Alochi: it would certainly be possible, but it would be awkward in practice. XML-as-data is often program generated, but XML-as-document is usually human edited text, and a no-mixed-content rule would just make it harder to edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid XML:

```
<div>
   Some text, and some <b>more</b> text.
</div>
```

The `text.` at the end is *still* enclosed in the `div` element.

Breakdown:

```
 Some text, and some  - Text node within div
 <b>more</b>          - b element within div (with own text node)
  text.               - Text node within div
```

These are all sibling nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> Ignoring the initial XML Declaration,
>   is the above also valid XML?

Yes, it is still enclosed within the `div` tag.

A useful explanation to this is found in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_element.asp).

> Text is always stored in text nodes. A
>   common error in DOM processing is to
>   navigate to an element node and expect
>   it to contain the text. However, even
>   the simplest element node has a text
>   node under it. For example, in
>   2005, there is an element
>   node (year), and a text node under it,
>   which contains the text (2005)

So, in your example, the're a text node for `text.` under the `div` element.

Answer (score -1):

According to "XML for the World Wide Web" by Elizabeth Castro (2001) 
the answer is yes with a special tag called CDATA

To prevent a parser from reading the HTML as XML, you could enclose the example above within CDATA like this:

```
<element>
    <![CDATA[
<div>
Some text, and some <b>more</b> text.
</div>
]]>
</element>
```

The `<![CDATA[` stops the text from being parsed until it reaches the closing `]]>`

Comment: I had misread the question thinking you wanted to embed tags into the text of an XML element. So this doesn't really apply to your question.